# How is a helium tank volume measured?

Tags: pressure, gas, volume

I'm comparing different helium tank offers and I found an interesting one which seems to be what I want, but I'm unsure regarding the volume.

It states:

> The content of gas of this tank is greater than the content of gas of an ordinary tank because the pressure is 300 bar: 20l / 5.2 m<sup>3</sup>

How is the volume measured in this case? $20l = 0.02m^3$ according to formulas.

I talked to a sales person who tried to convince me that $20l$ really mean $5.2m^3$ of helium. I was unsure, so I let it go, but I'm still confused.

$20l$ is clearly not $5.2m^3$. Can it be that they meant that the tank volume is $20l$ and a volume of $5.2m^3$ of helium (at normal pressure) is compressed in the tank, hence the $300 bar $ pressure? If so, what is *normal pressure* in this case?

Comment: Sounds legit. For the ideal gas 20l at 300bar is 6m3 at 1bar, but allowing for not-quite-linearity at 300bar, 5.2m3 comes close.

Comment: I'd worry whether I really want such an overpressurized tank, but if I'd be concerned just with quantity, I'd ask how much **kg** of helium I am purchasing

Comment: Normal pressure is likely STP (standard temperature and pressure) or similar.  Basically room temperature at sea level atmosphere.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Can't the mass of gas be computed from volume and pressure (assuming the temperature), supposing that the data they presented is correct?

Comment: Maybe one of you can post leave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 20 litres are at 300 bar, that expanded 300 times will be $6m^3$ at 1 bar. However, the ideal gas law works only for ideal gases, so the $5.2m^3$ figure sounds plausible.

To clairfy a comment exchange:

> I'd ask how much kg of helium I am purchasing – LLlAMnYP
>   Can't the mass of gas be computed from volume and pressure (assuming the temperature), supposing that the data they presented is correct? – Ionică Bizău

Yes, it can, but if we're talking money, just get the sales representative to tell you how many moles or kg you're purchasing. That's unambiguous and a conserved quantity. Calculations are error-prone and rely on approximations, like the ideal gas law, which, as we see, is about 15% off.

Answer (score 0):

Try the formulae in IC8367, Computing volumes of helium from 10 to 10,000 psia, published by the United States Bureau of Mines, this takes into account the compressabilty and the fact that a steel container will expand under pressure, so a 50 litre floodable voume container at 1 atmosphere absolute, isnt 15000 litres, bit like putting hot water into a hot water bottle it expands.

Also gas supplies calculate volumes of helium at a set temperature and pressure, try these figures, a 45 bottle gas pack at 196 bar will contain 14000 ft of helium, but for a helium/mixture it will contain 14750, and if pure O2 will be 17,000.

The formulae is pheonominal taking into account something called Poisiont ratio, I have all the information if anyone wants it.  just email me at colingoff@icloud.com

Just ran those figures through IC8367, it works in psi, so converted 300 bar at 14.51 psi, x 20 litre bottle at 59 fahrenheit, helium content comes out at 5515 litres, ie 5.5 m3, so the value you were given is about right.